# YouTube API Quota Extension for research

Tags: youtube-data-api

I need an extension to my YouTube API quota allotment to conduct research for my dissertation. I have been trying to get an estimate of the available resources and costs for extensions for an NSF grant but have not been able to get in contact with a human for several weeks despite filing the quota extension form.

Currently, I've been trapped in a loop with the youtube API compliance team where they continuously ask me for the following info.

In order to proceed further, please provide us the following information:

```
Provide API Client link and demo credentials

Screenshots and/or video recording(s) that clearly demonstrates how your API Client and its users access and use the YouTube API Services.

Documents relating to your implementation, access and use of YouTube API Services.
```

I have attached the required responses mulitple times and still receive the same message. For the first I have attached my python code for accessing the API (the only usage of the service), the second I have attached the pictures of the terminal window and the data output, for the third I have attached the project summary, description, and data collection plan for the project plus the first paper I published using the limited quota on YouTube.

I've repeatedly asked to be connected with a human to go through their needs but have had no response. The project has received a great deal of interest in the Economics community and I am under a great deal of pressure to continue the work, it is very stressful for a graduate student to bear especially when barred by an automated response. Please help D:

The service tag is 1-0726000027117